# How to remove cards, charts and calendar from tabs of all modules?

Tags: openxava

```
@Tab(editors ="List"
```

can be used in a per Module approach.

Can it be done for all modules at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tabs-default-values.xml file in src/main/resources/xava of your OpenXava project with this content:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>


<!DOCTYPE tabs-default-values SYSTEM "dtds/tabs-default-values.dtd">
 
<tabs-default-values>
 
    <tab editors="List">
        <for-all-models/>
    </tab>
 
</tabs-default-values>
```

Look at the reference doc:
https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/tab_en.html#Tabular%20data-Removing%20the%20Charts%20from%20list%20mode%20%28new%20in%20v5.7%29

Comment: I got `@Tab(editors ="List"` from the exact same link you provided. Just a few lines above. Sorry.